# Having difficulty calculating a derivative using the definition and limit question

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

My first question is how do we justify that the limit of $\sin (x)\sin \frac{1}{x}$ as $x$ tends to $0$ is $0$? Would we say $-\sin(x)\leq \sin (x)\sin (\frac{1}{x})\leq \sin (x)$ and then use the Sandwich rule as both the function to the left and right of $f(x)$ tend to $0$?

Comment: To your first question: yes. To your second question (which ideally according to the rules of this site would be separate), we can't actually see the question; are you being asked to prove something about this function at $0$? Perhaps that it is differentiable there? (It is fairly obviously differentiable elsewhere, by the basic calculus rules.) If so, hint: $1-\sqrt{1-x^2}=\frac{(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{x^2}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Comment: Let me delete it and start again! Sorry!

Comment: @Ian It won't let me post for another 20 minutes, but it asking what the derivative is, prove the derivative is continuous and that the derivative is not differentiable

Comment: @Ian I have uploaded the new question now

Comment: Your approach using Squeeze theorem is good, but the inequalities must be like this $-|\sin x| \leq \sin x\sin (1/x) \leq |\sin x|$. Your inequality is wrong in case $\sin x$ is negative. Hence better to use the absolute values. More generally you should be able to prove the following theorem (using Squeeze Theorem): *If $f(x)$ is bounded as $x \to a$ and $g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to a$ then $f(x)g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to a$.*